# default option in select box - angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 <select name="country" id="countries" ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by country.id" style="font-size:13px;" ng-model="sel_country"
      ng-change="set(sel_country)" >

      <option>--</option>

</select>

// countries object
$scope.countries = [{name: 'UNITED KINGDOM', id: 1 },{name: 'AUSTRIA', id: 2}];
```

How to show default option in select box using above code?

Comment: What do you want as your default option?

Comment: put your required option in ng-model. it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option-1**: use `value=""` within your `<option>` tag

```
 <select name="country" id="countries" ng-options="sel_country as country.name for country in countries track by country.id" style="font-size:13px;" ng-model="sel_country[0]"
  ng-change="set(sel_country)" >

        <option value="">-select-</option>

  </select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mqv5IRAQRPsOQvm67emx?p=preview)

**Option-2**: Use `ng-init` with `ng-model`

```
 <select ng-init="sel_country = countries[0]" name="country" id="countries" ng-options="sel_country as country.name for country in countries track by country.id" style="font-size:13px;" ng-model="sel_country"
  ng-change="set(sel_country)" >

        <option>-select-</option>

  </select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ifdv4qpR7M2h3MaXGhvY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have "--" as default value.

change

```
<option>--</option>
```

to

```
<option value="">--</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="country" 
    id="countries" 
    ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by country.id" 
    style="font-size:13px;" 
    ng-model="sel_country"
    ng-change="set(sel_country)" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>--</option>
</select>
```